# Android ListView Highlight Selected Row

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I am trying to highlight the selected row of items from listview. Here is how I set up my listview:

```
 public void buildCatListView(){
    //Code to get data from database

    }
    // Set the data into listview
    catlistview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(this));

    catlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {

            // Get the transaction record ID
            categoryID = _catlist.get(position)
                    .getCategoryID();

            for (int j = 0; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++)
                parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            // Change the background color of the selected element
            item.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(246, 206, 206));
        }
    });
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

And the XML file of my list view:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>
```

And the XML file of my list view row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplayCat"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtDisplayCatDesc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

It did highlight the selected row when clicked. But it behaved in a very weird way. Let's say I selected the first item, it's not only highlighting the first item but also the last. Then when I scroll down, the highlighted row sometimes will shift to second or third. I not sure why is it so.

Just wonder is there any alternate way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this property of `ListView`

```
android:listSelector="#99000000"
```

you can also create your own selector and set as background drawable

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! But how come when I scroll around my list view, the highlghted color will either remains at the top or bottom of my list view?